# Keep getting JavaScript messages in Geb test

Tags: javascript, grails, geb

Following this tutorial: 
http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/how-to-configure-webdriver-in-grails-for-your-geb-tests/

I do:

```
def "go to page"() {
    when:
        go "http://www.grails.org.mx"
    then:
        title == "GrailsMX | Groovy y Grails en tu idioma"  
}
```

When I run, I get hundreds of messages like this:

```
13,09 22:06:18:992 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@2fc9e7a5] ERROR javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://grails.org.mx/wp-content/themes/journalcrunch/js/cufon-yui.js] line=[7] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

Some of them are printed out multiple times?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what I should do about them?

Any tips?

Comment: try using waitFor{} check out this http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/intro.html#full_examples

Answer (score 0):

I think it's problem with your browser(disabled javascript).
Try check this: [read this](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/javascript.html#javascript_ajax_and_dynamic_pages)